# Could a USB wifi dongle be used as an Arduino Wifi module?

Tags: arduino, wifi, usb-device

I have seen many arduino compatible wifi modules that are rather expensive compared to some other types of modules. I am wondering what is the feasibility of using a consumer grade wifi usb dongle as a wifi module for an Arduino?

Take for instance [this module](http://www.microcenter.com/single_product_results.phtml?product_id=0376775). Is far cheaper than any of the arduino wifi modules. If it were possible to use one of these in my projects it would greatly reduce the cost of a wifi enabled projecct.

If something like that is possible what would be required to the two communicating?

Comment: The arduino would need to have a host USB stack and host-capable USB hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via USB? It would be difficult as you've been replied to. But, if the underlying device communicated on a hobby-friendly bus such as SPI or I²C, it would make things a lot more possible. Obviously, this would require in-depth knowledge of the hardware which would be impossible to come by and difficult to derive. In short: no; this is simply not worth the time and effort required and may not even be possible anyways.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a regular Ethernet shield for your arduino (with RJ45), you can turn it into wifi with a wifi adapter such as the Netgear WNCE2001. I did it and it works fine. I am able to make my arduino send data to by android tablet via a wifi access point. I am now struggling a bit to implement a peer-to-peer wifi connection from the arduino to the tablet without the external wifi access point in order to take it into my car, but I think this is achievable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea, the cost of Wifi chips is weird. I suspect the USB interface code on top of the TCPIP code is going to get rather heavy

Try this instead [ruggedcircuits - yellowjacket](http://ruggedcircuits.com/html/yellowjacket.html)